# Bigquery memory leak

Tags: java, optimization, google-bigquery, heap-memory

We maintain array of bigquery connections. That can scale up and down depending on the volume of the data and number of threads. What we see is that even though we shrink that array list by simply building a new arraylist and copy the subset of the existing one to the new one however the resources not claimed by garbaga collector thus heap size goes thru roof!

Any known issue with bigquery libraries?

```
BufferElement<ObjectType>[] newBuffer = createArray(newSize);
...
...
...
System.arraycopy(buffer, srcIdx, newBuffer, length1 + dstLength2, dstLength3);
buffer = newBuffer;
```

Comment: What makes you think that the old entries should be collected just because they're not referenced anymore? The Java GC doesn't make very many guarantees in this area.

Comment: The same piece of code for connection pooling is used for several other jdbc connections, mysql and vertica. We incorporated bigquery, we started having heap issue. What you suggest to ensure that the entries are collected?

Comment: I don't know exactly what is eating your memory, but in general, if you want to ensure something is released, you should explicitly call some `close()` or `release()` method — whatever is appropriate for your object. Perhaps these things support AutoCloseable?

Comment: That's the problem, unfortunately bigquery api does not expose such method to destruct the object explicitly same as vertica, mysql, SQL server jdbc driver. Once you release the reference for those connections, they are being reclaimed.

Comment: What exact class are you dealing with? I'm looking at [BigQueryConnection](https://code.google.com/p/jaspersoft-bigquery-datasource/source/browse/trunk/js-bigquery-datasource/src/main/java/com/jaspersoft/bigquery/connection/BigQueryConnection.java?r=5#102), which has a `close()` method. (I don't really know anything about BigQuery though, FYI)

Comment: Thank you jwd for the support and the link. They used the shutdown method of HttpTransport class and it does nothing :) 
  /**
   * Default implementation does nothing, but subclasses may override to possibly release allocated
   * system resources or close connections.

  public void shutdown() throws IOException {
  }

Comment: Interesting. I guess the next step would be to profile the app to see where the memory is going.

Comment: Created a mock big query connection and pointed data streaming to that mock bigquery which does nothing. Heam usage stays below 200M however google big query connection is used, it goes up to 16gb in few days. This is just data streaming so expection is that big query should maintain much data in memory anyway. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with pooling bigquery connections? Most web containers actually do pooling for keep alive http connections without holding a reference to httpurlconnection

Comment: With the connection pool, we maintain warm connections meaning that once some data is pushed, consecutive ones will be pushed and will be available for read without requiring any additional warm up period